# Insert special characters into the database without disrupting other characters

Tags: php, html, mysql, special-characters

In the back-end of my database (*phpmyadmin*), and in `my_table>Operations` directory, the setting for my *Collation* is already `utf8_general_ci`. If it's already in `utf8_general_ci`, do I have to change the *Collation* of each field/column of that table?

**Sample code:**

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="field1">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**insert.php**

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO table (column1) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$_POST["field1"]);
```

### Note:

Special characters like `ñ` is now *inserting properly* after the first method above, but when a user inputs `’` (not `'`), the character will be changed to `â€™`.

### Question:

How can I insert properly special characters without disrupting the other characters?

Comment: Sounds like your *input* is not actually UTF-8 encoded. Did you follow the duplicate in detail? Also see [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)